# Java FPDF libraries. Compression Issues

Tags: java, fpdf

I am using [Java FPDF](https://github.com/borisbrodski/Java-FPDF) libraries.

I successfully generated a document that have special chars, such as Euro and copyright symbol.

The document is rendered as expected (yes, I managed to resolve the charset encoding issues), but only if I set the compression to `false`, using `function myDoc.setCompression(false);`.

As soon as the compression is set to `true`, the Euro symbol is rendered as `â‚¬`, and the Copyright symbol is rendered as `Â©`.

I had a view to the libraries and everything looks fine to me. It is using the Java implementation of the [ZLIB algorithm](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/zip/Deflater.html), and the command written to the output file is `/Filter /FlateDecode`, as per the [PDF 1.3 reference](http://acroeng.adobe.com/PDFReference/PDF_1.3/PDF%20Reference%201.3.pdf) (page 54 referred to the document).

I know that the document isn't corrupt, because the PDF viewer recognizes it and render all the text and images as it should, apart from those special chars.

After many tests, I couldn't resolve the problem. My suspect is that there is a problem either in the compression libraries or in the viewer itself.

Should be there any problem with the Java code, does anyone know how to fix it?.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: What steps did you take to manage the encoding issues? Do you think there could be some inverse form of this operation that you should perform when rendering the PDF to support to compression?

Comment: Hi @Alex T. I create a String object as follows: `copyrightNotice = "Copyright ©2014"; copyrightNotice = new String(copyrightNotice.getBytes("UTF-8"), "ISO-8859-1");`. I do exactly the same with the Euro, but the libraries replace any Euro char with the char number 128. Regards

Comment: I just found a library for implementing the ZLIB Algorithm to support ISO-8859-1. (https://github.com/advancedrei/Zlib.Portable/blob/master/src/Zlib.Portable/Iso8859Dash1Encoding.cs) This may suggest that by default ZLIB doesn't support these characters?

Comment: Thanks Alex for your help. However, the proposed solution seems to be for C-Sharp, not for Java. Regards